# How to prevent empty List Error in Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails

I have the following HQL query in hibernate:

```
select x 
from Item as x
where x not in (select o.item from Opinion as o where o.user =:user)
```

This query works fine unless the subquery (`select o.item from Opinion as o where o.user =:user`) returns an empty list. In this case I got an error.

Is there a way to prevent Hibernate from raising an error when the subquery (`select o.item from Opinion as o where o.user =:user`) is empty?

How do I have to rewrite the query to make it work even for empty (`select o.item from Opinion as o where o.user =:user`)?

Comment: Is this SQL or HQL? In case of SQL, which database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trivial way I see is

```
select x 
from Item as x
where (select count(distinct o.item) from Opinion as o where o.user =:user) = 0
```

Or (*untested)

```
select x 
from Item as x
where not exists (from Opinion as o where o.item = x and o.user =:user)
```

Comment: Assume that I need select x from Item as x where x in :someList what can I that no error occur if someList is empty?

Comment: @confile Are the above approaches failing for you?

Comment: The second one is working fine. But how do I do it when in want to have x in (...)

Comment: @confile Try to use [coalesce](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3099) to see if you can get what you need.